# Add 'Website' platform to facebook app

Tags: facebook, web-applications, facebook-opengraph

I am building an app on facebook, I was going through the 'Getting Started with Open Graph' page by Facebook Developers. The author asks us to 'Add Platform' by clicking at a button with the same name at the bottom of the page, but no such button exists. What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Head to https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Then select your app or create a new app in case you haven't

Next you should get something like this (App dashboard):

[image: Your app dashboard]

Now click on settings, here's the <kbd>Add Platform</kbd> button:

[image: App settings]

click on the <kbd>Add Platform</kbd> button, then select the platform you're working on and config it

[image: Platforms can be added]

Comment: Would I add platforms/websites for multiple urls that redirect to the same domain ??