# Facebook -> Apps -> Website with Facebook Login -> How do I still use this? It does not appear in my developer page anymore?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to set up social login (through oneall.com) on a new website I am making. I have done this before with other sites, and had little trouble.

Since Facebook has changed its developer interface quite a bit over the last few months, it has caused me a lot of misery!

I am not even sure how to set this up anymore. The oneall tutorial shows the simple, previous method, in which you just click the check box for website with Facebook login, add the url, and done.

I would really appreciate any and all help with this. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855711/add-website-platform-to-facebook-app/20861065#20861065

Comment: Thanks Adam, I tried that, but it still did not accept it.

I am trying loginradius now instead of oneall to see how it works out.

Comment: You want to add `App Domain` or `App website (callback)`?

Comment: Correction, it is now working. It must have just been a lag somewhere in the process. Thanks Adam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Setting > Add Platform > add Website`

You will see Site URL:

Fill "xxxxx.api.oneall.com" (xxx is your subdomain)

Fill App Domains for the same values.

It should be done. (May be)

Sandbox is appear on Status & Preview. You can change according to your need.